# click event of a button to fire fileupload control in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, file-upload

I have a file upload Control and I have made this invisible.

I want to enable a browse `Button` for  that file upload control when I click another `Button`.

How can I do it?

Comment: If the file upload control was invisible, how would the user select which file to upload?

Comment: get an overview here http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html

Answer (score 2):

First make a file up loader like [this one](http://asp.net-tutorials.com/controls/file-upload-control/)

To upload a file you need to do 2 things

1) Select the file. (click browse button)

2) Send it to server. (click the upload button)

So first lets write a java-script to do these.`

```
<script type="text/javascript" > 
function uploadImage() {
    $('#MainContent_UploadButton').click()
}
function selectFile() {
    $('#MainContent_FileUploadControl').click();
}
</script>
```

Now make the file upload controller upload itself as soon as a file is selected

```
 <asp:FileUpload id="MainContent_FileUploadControl" runat="server" 
            onChange="uploadImage()" class="hidden"/>
```

Then make a new button and let it select the file as soon as it is clicked.

```
    <asp:Button ID="MainContent_UploadButton" runat="server" Text="Upload File" 
            OnClientClick="selectFile(); return false;" />
```

The most important point is put "return false" in the onClientClick field. It will block the buttons post back and let you choose a file without refreshing the page.

Now hide the unwanted components using css and you are done !!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not possible. This would likely be a security issue if a script could upload (or at least trigger the upload process) invisible from any user interaction.

---

**Update:**

Seems that someone actually [developed a solution to hide the upload control](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html). From what I read it seems to take some effort to develop and uses JavaScript.

Personally, I wouldn't dare to guarantee that this works on all platforms (just imagine someone with a BlackBerry or Windows Phone visits your website...) and thus avoid it.

Comment: Can I upload a file in a button click event without using fileupload control?

Comment: After a file has been (manually) selected by the user through a file upload control (`<input type="file" ... />), you could use JavaScript to start the upload.

Comment: @naveen Which part are you refering to as "not true at all"? Your link points to some ajax wrapper around the file upload control.

Comment: OP wanted a technique to hide the ugly fileupload it seems. its very possible. please note that i haven't down voted you since i get your point too... :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" style="display:none;"/>
<input id="btnFileUpload" type="button" value="Add" runat="server" />

btnFileUpload.Attributes.Add("onclick", "document.getElementById('" + FileUpload1.ClientID + "').click();");
```